# Rsyslogd module Error

Tags: rsyslog

I want to use  capture packets by rsyslog with impcap but when I use it on configuration file I get this error:

> rsyslogd: version 8.2102.0, config validation run (level 1), master
> config /etc/rsyslog.conf
> rsyslogd: could not load module 'impcap',
> errors: trying to load module /usr/lib/rsyslog/impcap.so:
> /usr/lib/rsyslog/impcap.so: cannot open shared object file: No such
> file or directory [v8.2102.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2066 ]

how can I install this package or where is it?

Comment: Try https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog/#project-provided-packages.

Comment: it`s not helping